# Magento 2 Create Product grid columns

Tags: magento2, grid, product-listing

How to Create New custom column in product grid in magento 2.

**`Thanks.`**

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Magento 2 add custom column in product grid?](https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/170070/magento-2-add-custom-column-in-product-grid)

Comment: I want to in catalog>product section.

Answer (score 0):

**app/code/Vendor/Module/etc/module.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<config xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:Module/etc/module.xsd">
    <module name="Vendor_Module" setup_version="1.0.0">
        <sequence>
            <module name="Magento_Catalog"/>
        </sequence>
    </module>
</config>
```

**app/code/Vendor/Module/view/adminhtml/ui_component/product_listing.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?> 
<listing xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:module:Magento_Ui:etc/ui_configuration.xsd"> 
    <columns name="product_columns"> 
        <column name="custom_column_name" component="Magento_Ui/js/grid/columns/select" sortOrder="76"> 
            <settings> 
                <addField>true</addField> 
                <options class="Magento\Config\Model\Config\Source\Yesno"/> 
                <filter>select</filter> 
                <dataType>select</dataType> 
                <sortable>false</sortable> 
                <label translate="true">Custom Column Name/label> 
            </settings> 
        </column> 
    </columns> 
</listing>
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer but your answer custom column ASC and DSC working?